# MYSQL - Erro código 1644

Tags: mysql

Tenho duas database, quando uma trigger é disparada ela gera um insert em outra database é um artifício para gerar log :

O esquema é esse: database de nome local tem uma tabela chamada tab_manifesto e é feito um insert nesta e a trigger dispara um insert no database local_log.log_tab_manifesto.

Segue abaixo a construção e um exemplo do erro na hora de fazer o insert.

```
USE local_log;

delimiter $$
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `local_log`.`log_tab_manifesto`$$ 
CREATE TABLE `log_tab_manifesto` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_nome` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `data_hora` datetime NOT NULL,
  `host` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `operacao` varchar(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'I-Insert, D-Delete, U-Update',
  `manifesto_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `man_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uni_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `filial_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'numero da carta frete de cada filial, exemplo foz_id',
  `mot_mot_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mot_est_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `veic_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `man_data` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `man_origem` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `man_destino` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `man_status` varchar(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'null  ou 0 = Viajando / 1 = chada / 2 = descarregando / 3 = finalizado',
  `man_ordem_chegada` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Ordena a Chegada dos Manifestos',
  `man_cancelado` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `man_descarga` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

    -- CRIANDO trigger PARA A TABELA - triggers SÃO CRIADAS NA DATABASE DE ***PRODUÇÃO***
DELIMITER $$

USE `local`$$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `local`.`tg_tab_manifesto_after_i`$$
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1`
TRIGGER `local`.`tg_tab_manifesto_after_i`
AFTER INSERT ON `local`.`tab_manifesto`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION /*DECLARAR EXECEÇÃO*/ 
    RESIGNAL SQLSTATE '21S01' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'TRIGGER tg_tab_manifesto_after_i';/*RETORNA O NOME DA TRIGGER EM CASO DE ERRO*/
    /*LOG - INSERIR NOVO REGISTRO DE LOG */
    set @id = (select ifnull(max(id)+1,1) from local_log.log_tab_manifesto);    
    insert into local_log.log_tab_manifesto
        values(         
            @id,
            substring_index(session_user(),'@',1),
            now(),
            substring_index(session_user(),'@',-1),
            'I',
            NEW.`log_tab_manifesto`.`manifesto_id`,
            NEW.`log_tab_manifesto`.`man_id`,
            NEW.`log_tab_manifesto`.`uni_id`,
            NEW.`log_tab_manifesto`.`filial_id`,
            NEW.`log_tab_manifesto`.`mot_mot_id`,
            NEW.`log_tab_manifesto`.`mot_est_id`,
            NEW.`log_tab_manifesto`.`veic_id`,
            NEW.`log_tab_manifesto`.`man_data`,
            NEW.`log_tab_manifesto`.`man_origem`,
            NEW.`log_tab_manifesto`.`man_destino`,
            NEW.`log_tab_manifesto`.`man_status`,
            NEW.`log_tab_manifesto`.`man_ordem_chegada`,
            NEW.`log_tab_manifesto`.`man_cancelado`,
            NEW.`log_tab_manifesto`.`man_descarga`
        );  
end$$
```

O erro acontece aqui nesse insert abaixo:

```
INSERT INTO 
tab_manifesto(
    uni_id,
    filial_id,
    mot_mot_id,
    mot_est_id,
    veic_id,
    man_origem,
    man_destino
) values (
    1,
    NULL,
    30,
    NULL,
    327,
    'FOZ',
    ' SAO PAULO'
);
```

> Error Code: 1644. TRIGGER tg_tab_manifesto_after_i

Alguém poderia me ajudar a corrigir esse erro ?

Comment: O erro não é nessa linha ? `TRIGGER `local`.`tg_tab_manifesto_after_i``

Comment: Qual a versão do MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei esse [site](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-error-codes-and-messages-1600-1649#error_er_signal_exception) que diz que esse erro é definido pelo usuário... então dei uma olhada novamente no código para ver onde eu escrevi isso e achei as linhas são essas

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION /*DECLARAR EXECEÇÃO*/ 
RESIGNAL SQLSTATE '21S01' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'TRIGGER tg_tab_manifesto_after_i';/*RETORNA O NOME DA TRIGGER EM CASO DE ERRO*/
```

Comentei essas linhas e rodei o script novamente, ai sim consegui uma mensagem de erro mais detalhada:

> 08:34:09  INSERT INTO   tab_manifesto(   uni_id,   filial_id,   mot_mot_id,   mot_est_id,   veic_id,   man_origem,   man_destino  ) values (   1,   NULL,   30,   NULL,   327,   'FOZ',   ' SAO PAULO'  ) Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'NEW.log_tab_manifesto.manifesto_id' in 'field list'   0.031 sec

Não existe NEW.**log_tab_manifesto**.manifesto_id o correto é NEW.**tab_manifesto**.manifesto_id

Obrigado a todos pela atenção, lição aprendida!